# Error while creating Docker network (Error response from daemon: Failed to program FILTER chain)

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, docker, linux-networking

System Information:

- OS: `Armbian 20.08.17 Buster on RockPro64`
- Docker version: `18.09.1, build 4c52b90`
- IPtables version: `iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables)`

When trying to create a Docker network, I get the following:

```
~# docker network create container-bridge
Error response from daemon: Failed to program FILTER chain: iptables failed: iptables --wait -I FORWARD -o br-1288ffd00090 -j DOCKER: iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables):  RULE_INSERT failed (Invalid argument): rule in chain FORWARD
 (exit status 4)
```

Does anyone know what the cause/fix is, or a workaround? I have not been able to create any docker networks which is a problem as the built-in ones do not have a DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Having done more research, I came across an answer in the form of a forum post: https://forum.armbian.com/topic/13931-omv5-fresh-installation-with-docker-docker-network-create-failes/

The proposed solution which indeed worked, was:

```
update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
update-alternatives --set arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy
update-alternatives --set ebtables /usr/sbin/ebtables-legacy
```

However, I'm not marking this question as solved, as it seems to be more of a workaround than a solution.

Comment: that means your kernel doesn't have iptables-over-nftables support (and maybe also directly no nftables support). It's a kernel compilation configuration problem.

Comment: @A.B Does that mean it should be reported to the maintainers of the Armbian kernel package?

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/armbian/build/blob/v2020.08/config/kernel/linux-rockchip64-current.config everything appears to be present (including CONFIG_NFT_COMPAT). So I don't know what's missing for this to work. But do you really need it? I guess no.

Comment: @A.B Yeah, I guess I'll just stick to the workaround since it works and seems to have no major downsides